# Does $\frac{2z-1}{z-1}$ map $\mathbb D\backslash[1/2, 1]$ onto $\mathbb C\backslash (-\infty, 0]$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to construct an analytic isomorphism between these two sets, and I think that I've found one. The issue is I have no idea how to prove it is an analytic isomorphism. How should I go about this?

Comment: Your so sure about $\mathbb D\backslash[1/2, 1]$?
How about 2/3?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure.

Comment: You might want to study some Möbius Transformation. :)

Comment: I think I multiplied by -1 by mistake. Does $2z-1/z-1$ map onto? I used a Möbius Transform to derive this by taking $1/2$ to $0$ and $1$ to $-\infty$, but I need to prove this is a bijection.

Comment: If you know how Möbius transformations behave, you should see that this transformation maps the unit disk to a half-plane. So $\mathbb{D}\setminus [1/2,1]$ is mapped to a half-plane minus a closed ray. Try constructing the map in the other direction, I think it's easier to see how to do that.